# iOS: Practices for storing a view

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My app allows users to customize (add `UILabel`s and `UIImage`s to a `UIView`. I want the user to be able to retrieve the same view (everything remains at the same location where it was defined). I'm thinking CoreData. I guess I can store everything necessary in a `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` including a subview's frame and whatever the user puts inside that view (can be an image or text depending on whether it is a `UILabel` or `UIImage`). The storage structure I have in my head is the following:

`Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`

- "frame" : `CGRect`
- "image" : `UIImage` OR "label" : `UILabel`

Once I have this ready I can just convert the dictionary into NSData and stuff it into core data.
But is this the correct way of storing views? Any alternative/suggestion on this? Thanks!

=================================UPDATE=================================
The structure I ended up using looks something like this:

`NSDictionary`

- "frame" : `CGRect`
- "content" : `UIImage`'s path on disk / text (for labels)
- "type" : "Img" / "Txt"

Since I'm using CoreData, I only needed to make my "view" object extend NSManagedObject and have a dictionary property. This way, the encoding process was no longer needed.

Comment: `UIView` implements `NSCoding`, you should be able to serialize them to data and back with `NSKeyedArchiver` and `Unarchiver`

Comment: I don't know if this is the right way. I would create my own objects per the user created views and save them. And recreate them whenever user comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to creating a dictionary is fair. In a number of ways it would be better to create a custom class (or set of) as these are more specific and provide more compiler checks.

In either case, archiving the store to data is the correct approach (using `NSCoding`).

Once you have the data you should save it directly to disk rather than using Core Data. Core Data doesn't provide any advantages when storing a single large binary data blob.

Using Core Data properly will only help you if you have many views that you want to store and you don't need to reload them all at the same time. If doing this you wouldn't use a dictionary or data, you would define entities with appropriate attributes.

Comment: By saving to disk did you mean saving the whole dictionary (somehow) or just the image then adding a url to the image to the dictionary which is to be saved in CoreData?

Comment: Archiving the dictionary to data (like you planned) then saving the data to disk. Don't put a dictionary into Core Data, it won't help you.

Comment: I did end up using what I had planned before, but the problem was that I wasn't able to use `Dictionary`'s because they weren't objects. Fortunately `NSDictionary`'s kicked in and helped solve the problem. By making my view extend `CoreData`'s `NSManagedObject`, I no longer needed to encode anything which was neat :)